# Pure CSS centering of absolutely positioned image of unknown height

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div id=wrapper>
  <img id=my_img src="img.png" />
</div>

<style>
  #my_img{
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
  }
</style>
```

I need to center #my_img within the #wrapper, absolutely positioned 60px from the bottom of #wrapper.  The catch is that the width of #my_img is not always known -- when max-height takes effect for a very wide viewport.

- display: block; and margin: 0 auto; will not work for an absolutely positioned element.
- display: inline-block; and text-align: center on the wrapper aligns the left edge of the image at center in both FF and Chrome.
- left: 50%; margin-left: -width/2; won't work because I won't always know the width.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Your first option works if you add `left: 0`  and `right: 0`, and `position: relative` to wrapper

Comment: @DenisSheremet adding `left:0` and `right: 0` to the wrapper didn't work, but adding the same to the image did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

[Top property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp/)

Setting top/left/bottom/right to 0 would solve your problem possibly.

Found on: [Source](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt)

Comment: left 0, right 0 on the image fixed the problem.  For my specific case, I removed the top 0 and changed bottom to 60px.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

left : 50%;
transform : translateX(-50%);

Comment: I had already tried this solution.  It worked in FF and Chrome, but IE already centered the image as I wanted with `display: inline-block` on the image and `text-align: center` on the wrapper.  The transform then caused the image to be  offset 50% left of center.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I had tried the combination of `text-align: center` on the wrapper with `transform: translate(-50%,0)` and it didn't work for IE.  Your solution does solve the problem.